# Function Reference - create_resources in puppet

Tags: puppet

refer https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources

```
# A hash of user resources:
$myusers = {
  'nick' => { uid    => '1330',
              gid    => allstaff,
              groups => ['developers', 'operations', 'release'], },
  'dan'  => { uid    => '1308',
              gid    => allstaff,
              groups => ['developers', 'prosvc', 'release'], },
}

create_resources(user, $myusers)
```

Read the explanation for this function `create_resources`, but not sure what result after `create_resources(user, $myusers)`

Does it create two users `nick` and `dan` with nominated uid, gid and groups?

#### updates:

some explanations from web.

```
Listing 12-79. Hiera lookup of sysadmin hash
root@puppet-master-hiera-ubuntu:/etc/puppet/data# hiera sysadmins
{"spencer"=>{"uid"=>1861, "groups"=>"root", "gid"=>300}, "william"=>{"uid"=>11254,
"groups"=>"root", "gid"=>300}}

   Now we can use a function called create_resources() to generate Puppet resources from this hash, as shown in

Listing 12-80. create_resources example

$sysadmins = hiera('sysadmins')

create_resources(user, $sysadmins)

    Listing 12-81 shows the output.

Listing 12-81. Applying the create_resources example from Listing 12-80

root@puppet-master-hiera-ubuntu:/etc/puppet# puppet apply create_resources.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for puppet-master-hiera-ubuntu.green.gah in environment production in
0.11 seconds
Notice: /User[spencer]/ensure: created
Notice: /User[william]/ensure: created
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.32 seconds
```

I can't properly set and prove it in my environment, but above sample gives the answer, it DOES create user accounts with hash in `create_resources` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_resources` will just map

```
# A hash of user resources:
$myusers = {
  'nick' => { uid    => '1330',
              gid    => allstaff,
              groups => ['developers', 'operations', 'release'], },
  'dan'  => { uid    => '1308',
              gid    => allstaff,
              groups => ['developers', 'prosvc', 'release'], },
}

create_resources(user, $myusers)
```

into

```
  user{'nick':
    uid    => '1330',
    gid    => allstaff,
    groups => ['developers', 'operations', 'release'], },
  }
  user{'dan':
    uid    => '1308',
    gid    => allstaff,
    groups => ['developers', 'prosvc', 'release'], },
  }
```

So those users will be passed to user provider. You can test it easily creating a users.pp file with your recipes, and testing it with `puppet apply --noop` :

```
# puppet apply --noop users.pp 
Notice: Compiled catalog for yourfqdn in environment production in 0.15 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/User[nick]/ensure: current_value absent, should be present (noop)
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/User[dan]/ensure: current_value absent, should be present (noop)
```

Notice that if users already exist, puppet apply wont do anything

Comment: After map and pass to user provider, how do I use it? can you give a sample? For example, I need the user (nick) to be created.

Comment: You use the function call just like any other manifest - via `puppet master` or `puppet apply`.

Comment: do you mean, with `create_resources()`, after I apply the pp files, two user (nick and dan) will be created (if not created before)?

Comment: That's it. I've appended to answer results of `puppet apply --noop`